# How to find out if geonodes's viewer is active?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Using python i can access the node
`bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"].nodes["Viewer.001"]`
But how can I find out if it is currently active for preview?
[image]

Comment: I don't think the node has a exposed property for that. But you can find the spreadsheet area, get its space and check if `object_eval_state`is set to `VIEWER_NODE`. That should be the case, except if the user comes to another object eval state after that.